# Python pandas: Applying rolling sum on pivot table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I created a dataframe using pivot_table command.Dataframe has 351 rows and 120 columns. The dataframe looks like follow:

```
RY          2011                                              ...   2020
Month   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  ... 3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
ID                                                                                  
AB10    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
AB1286  0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
AB1951  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
AB2 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
AB2338  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Now I want to calculate the rolling sum of 12 months for ID. I wrote following command to calculate the rolling sum:

```
df.groupby('ID').rolling(12,on='Month').sum()
```

However, it gave the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid on specified as Month, must be a column (of DataFrame), an Index or None
```

Could anyone help me in fixing the issue?

Comment: What was your original `pandas.DataFrame` columns like? Was it `["Year", "Month", "ID", "value"]`? It might be more simple to obtain the desired results using that layout instead.

Comment: @AlexFortin Yes actual dataframe was ["Year", "Month", "ID", "value"]. The reason I converted into pivot table was I want to get the rolling sum from period 2011 to 2020. Few IDs do not have data for few years or month

Answer (score 1):

Try running that code *before* creating a pivot table. But, make sure that you first create a datetime column with something like:

`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'].astype(str) + '-' + df['Month'].astype(str) + '-01')`

and then:

`df.groupby('ID').rolling(12,on='Date').sum()`

Comment: I liked your idea of converting year and month into date. However, I still need to create the pivot_table. Because, few IDs may not have data on some date.so to avoid the missing details, I want to create the pivot tabke. After creating pivot table on ID and date when I ran the second command it throws this error "invalid on specified as Date, must be a column (of DataFrame), an Index or None"

Comment: You may have to reindex the data with `pd.MultiIndex.from_product()`

Answer (score 0):

What does "ID" contain? Have you tried transposing the pivot table by using?

```
df.T.groupby('ID').rolling(12,on='Month').sum()
```